# Physical security for portable computers - any alternative to Kensington locks?

Tags: physical-security

What can you use for theft-proofing portables aside from a Kensington lock, or a secure computer cabinet? Or have you had good results from using the former?

Comment: Is this primarily for theft-proofing in the office or also on the move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives / supplements to a Kensington lock:

- locks that go into another slot, such as the [Targus Video Port Lock](http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.asp?sku=PA496U).
- [physical plates](http://www.securitykit.com/laptop-plate40010.htm) to attach it to a table
- a conspicuous laptop [asset tag](http://www.idtagit.co.uk/security_tags.htm)
- or you could try this [cunning product](http://www.yankodesign.com/2008/10/14/this-cheese-is-not-for-you/)!

Comment: The Targus product is total news to me - cool, I'll be taking a peek on their site now

Comment: Looking at VGA port in my notebook, Targus lock wouldn't work. The port has no screws.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent anti-theft has to be integrated in the laptop, otherwise it'd be to heavy and impractical to use. The only anti-theft integrated by default in laptops is Kensington lock. There are some more advanced version of these, like for example ones, that have alarm.

Some business laptops have remote drive encryption, that could be activated in case of theft. But that's for the case, where you're worried about physical security of data, not the hardware itself.